# 2D array consisting of 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I know similar question have been asked but, I'm crating a game with C# and Unity and I'm trying to create chunk system, I've created an array

```
bool[,] chunkData = new bool[chunkWidth, chunkHeight];
```

now this array represents area of 32x32 tiles - one chunk, now I'd like to have another 2D array which will store all the chunks
The reason I've posted this question is because I'd like to ask if you can think of better idea of doing it, since I've never done such thing before.

Comment: Make the chunk a class since you probably will need other properties in the chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way for this is to wrap up the `chunkData` into a class, and then you can use any container to store a large collection of them. e.g.

```cs
public class Chunk
{
    private bool[,] data;
    public Chunk(int width, int height)
    {
        data = new bool[width, height];
    }

    public bool GetChunkDataAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return data[x, y];
    }

    public void SetChunkDataAt(int x, int y, bool value)
    {
        data[x, y] = value;
    }
}
```

Some error handling is omitted; the encapsulation makes it impossible to re-assign chunk data array from the outside, but if that should be it, keep it public is not *that* bad.

And then you can something like this:

```cs
Chunk[] chunkArray;
List<Chunk> chunkList;
// ...
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `List<bool[,]>` work just as the same? Why do you _need_ `Chunk`? Are there any other functions that need to be coded also besides a getter and setter?

Comment: Yes it works the same, and you can totally use a `List<bool[,]>` if such design is not worthy the extra time. I currently can think of 3 points that explain why this method is better. (not universally, though, simplicity is also an advantage)

Comment: 1. Encapsulation. The chunk data is likely going to work and interact with other data in your game, and, as development goes, more operations or properties may need to depend on it. This makes the (potential) future integration easier, which fits OOP design principles too. Overdesigning **CAN** happen, so again, not a universal solution.

Comment: 2. Readability. Wrapping up a special type of data into a class improves readability; consider another frequently-used `visitedData` of type `bool[,]` is to be added into the game; their declaration looks the same.

Comment: 3. Container Properties. `List` is not randomly accessible, while array is; depending on your needs, multiple choices of containers may be adopted. Every container has their way to be used, and adding a 2d-array-accessor right after them may cause confusion. It can be somewhat better if we keep the accessing of data encapsulated into an interface. This is actually quite minor and between encapsulation and readability.

Comment: Surely they may not be convincing enough, or I could be making some errors in my descriptions. But this is just one way of designing; any other reasons may beat this solution.

Comment: Agree mostly, although I am lost on your point of `List<T>` not being randomly accessible. It **does** implement an indexer to make statements like `data[5]` available, and it does internally implement arrays for storage.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that; sorry for the mistake. thanks!